# Passing Layouts (and manipulating regions) through CollectionView (Marionette / Backbone)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I'm trying to pass a layout into a CollectionView, and then manipulate the regions inside of it.

Right now, I'm successfully sending a layout into the CollectionView (which is in it's own region) like so:

```
main_layout.main_region.show(new CollectionView({
   itemView: ALayout,
   collection : someCollection
}));
```

I then can see that the layout is getting rendered. However, I can't figure out a way to modify (or even touch) the regions in 'ALayout'. Is there a way to do this? In the end, I'm trying to get a collection of 'panes' with a layout inside each one that has the same regions, and paint those regions somehow.

In addition, I was originally just passing an ItemView into the CollectionView, but I could figure out a way to add regions into that ItemView. If possible, I would like to control these regions in the file I pass it (be it a Layout or an ItemView).

Does anyone have any experience with this?

---

**Edit:**
Okay, so I found a hint with using the Backbone.BabySitter that comes with Marionette -- from this documentation that talks about CollectionView's children [here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-itemvieweventprefix). So now my code looks like this.

```
var collectionViewToUse = new CollectionView({
    itemView: ALayout,
    collection : someCollection
});

main_layout.main_region.show(collectionViewToUse);

collectionViewToUse.children.each(function(view) {
  console.log(view);
  //This fails.
  view.regionManagers.someRegion.show('HHHHHH');
  //So does this, if I run it instead
  view.someRegion.show('Anything');
});
```

The backbone view instance is getting logged, so I think I'm on to something here. Can anyone tell me how to manipulate the regions from this step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I have the answer to this issue. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!

The answer was down the path of using BabySitter. You bascially instantiate a CollectionView, then use BabySitter to loop through it and do something to each view. So if you pass it a layout:

```
var collectionViewToUse = new CollectionView({
    itemView: ALayout,
    collection : someCollection
});

main_layout.main_region.show(collectionViewToUse);

collectionViewToUse.children.each(function(view) {
   view.someRegion.show(new SomeView({model : view.model });
});
```

So basically, you can pass Collection view a Layout instead of an ItemView, then loop through the 'views' and pass new views into the regions.

Please comment with any improvements or if this was of any help to anyone else!

Comment: This errors telling me there that I must specify an ItemView which the  Layout is not.

Comment: Strange. I have this working in production on my project. Can you post a gist with the error/? Which version of Marionette/Backbone are you using? If you're interested, post some of your code and I'll compare it to mine as well!

Comment: Yep that was an issue with my code.  I'm doing this in a composite view and in onCompositeCollectionRendered.  when I call chidren.each view.someRegion is undefined.

Comment: maybe different versions of backbone/marionette are in use?

Comment: I thought the same at first, but I thought @dstarh verified it was something else in his code that was causing the issue. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I found a slight modification of this pattern by encapsulating the logic inside the Collection itself rather then modifying it from the outside.

```
var collectionViewToUse = new CollectionView({
    itemView: ALayout,
    collection : someCollection,

    onBeforeItemAdded: function(view) {
        view.on('show', function() {

            view.someRegion.show(
                new SomeView({
                    model : view.model // view.model is model of Layout
                })
            );

        });
    }
});

main_layout.main_region.show(collectionViewToUse);
```

All the answers posted suffer of a `model` being attached to the `Layout` while the model is only there to be passed to one of the sub-views.